# Closed orientable three manifold with finite cover by $S^1 \times S^2$ or $T^3$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have been thinking about a problem where I can conclude that I have a closed orientable three manifold which is covered by $S^1 \times S^2$ or $S^1 \times T^2$. I think that the geometrization theory allows me to describe the possible manifolds explicitly, but not being so confident with that theory I am wondering if someone could tell me what are the possibilities as well as some explanation.

Comment: You can find this in Scott's paper "The geometries of 3-manifolds".

Comment: The only orientable $3$-manifolds finitely covered by $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^2$ are $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^2$ itself and $\mathbb{RP}^3\# \mathbb{RP}^3$.